# Wrong permissions after sudo midnight commander

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sudo, midnight-commander

I sometimes start Midnight Commander as superuser with the command `sudo mc` to do some operations on the current working directory as superuser.

But this results in `~/.mc` having the wrong permissions, which I need to fix manually.

Any solution?

**Edit:**

I accepted an answer. I want to further add, that `.mc` is a directory, so my solution goes like this:

```
$ cd ~  
~$ sudo chown -R mit.mit .mc
~$ chmod 775 .mc 
~$ cd .mc 
~$ chmod -R 664 .mc 
~/.mc$ chmod 775 cedit
```

It seems not to be a good idea after installing `mc` to use `sudo` on its first start.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it instead of the incomplete one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the permissions on your `~/.mc` file like this:

```
chmod 664 ~/.mc
```

Make sure you do this as a regular user. This will set the permissions for the file to read and write for the owner (which should be your user) and root. And read only for anyone else.